# Importing Selected Spreadsheets

Tags: import, version-10, excel, spreadsheets

Consider the PISA study report, which contains dozens separate spreadsheets in each respective excel files (see http://www.oecd.org/pisa/keyfindings/pisa-2012-results-volume-iv.htm) Is there any way to call on a particular spreadsheet when one import the material?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it is a [duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) and it has [already been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29636/10397). Please at least [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to [improve it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Particularly, include a minimum example of the code you are working on.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `XLS` file is in this URL:

```
url = "http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013061P1T001.XLS";
```

This gives you the list of sheets in the `XLS` file

```
sheetslist = Import[url, {"XLS", "Sheets"}];
```

And you can `Import` the second sheet by

```
Import[url, {"Sheets", sheetslist[[2]]}]
```

---

Backtracking, now to get that URL...

Get a list of links in the page:

```
urlHome="http://www.oecd.org/pisa/keyfindings/pisa-2012-results-volume-iv.htm";
linklist=Import[urlHome, "Hyperlinks"];
```

`Select` only the ones that point to *doi.org* as those are the `XLS` files

```
urldoi = Select[linklist, StringMatchQ[#, "http://dx.doi.org" ~~ __] &]
```

You can confirm that by fetching the URL headers

```
headers = URLFetch[#, "Headers"] & /@ urldoi ;

headers[[All, 3, 2]]
```

> {"http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013061P1T001.XLS", \
>   "http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013061P1T002.XLS", \
>   "http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013061P1T003.XLS", \
>   "http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013061P1T004.XLS", \
>   "http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013061P1G001.XLS", \
>   "http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013061P1T005.XLS", \
>   "http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013061P1T006.XLS", \
>   "http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013061P1G002.XLS", \
>   "http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013061P1T007.XLS", \
>   "http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013061P1G003.XLS", \
>   "http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013061P1G003.XLS", \
>   "http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013061P1T008.XLS", \
>   "http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013061P1G004.XLS", \
>   "http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013041P1T010.XLS", \
>   "http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013041P1T011.XLS", \
>   "http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013061P1T010.XLS", \
>   "http://statlinks.oecdcode.org/982013061P1T009.XLS"}